# search issue in laravel model is not found

Tags: php, laravel

I used a search code from GitHub and it worked perfectly on the local host. But when I uploaded on a shared host this error appeared

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/halahait/untitled3/resources/views/terminal/search.blade.php)

and when i returned data as json

```
{
  "status": "false",
  "message": "this model not found"
}
```

this is the code wrote in the web file in laravel

```
Route::post('search',function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
$terminals=Search::search(
    //model
    "terminal" ,
    //fields you wants to search
    ['customer' , 'mac_address'] ,
    $request->search  ,
    //back with all raws
    null,
    ['id'  , 'asc'] ,
    true ,
    30
);
return view('terminal.search',compact('terminals'));
});
```

this is the view

```
@foreach($terminals as $trm)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$trm->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$trm->customer}}</td>
                    <th>{{$trm->mac_address}}</th>
                    <th>{{$trm->modem_type}}</th>
                    <th>{{$trm->satellite}}</th>
                  </tr>  
@endforeach
```

and this is the search form

```
<form class="form-header" action="/searchh" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input class="au-input au-input--xl" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for customer's info..." />
                    <button class="au-btn--submit" type="submit">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Comment: what package are you using to search?

Comment: github.com.zizohassan.full-text-search-laravel @EliasSoares

Answer (score 0):

That's happen because the package that you are using return an JSON, not an array or object, so you can not `foreach` a JSON directly.

Reading the [source code for Search](https://github.com/zizohassan/full-text-search-laravel/blob/b3ddc81b6b3d1b30dd017377d3f5e614b3740919/src/Search.php#L66) class, found this line:

```
return json_encode(['status' => 'false' , 'message' => "this model not found"]);
```

What means that the search method will return an string that contains a JSON in case of failure.

To catch this situation inside PHP, you will need to `json_decode` the string and check if `status` is false:

```
Route::post('search',function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
$terminals = Search::search(
    //model
    "terminal" ,
    //fields you wants to search
    ['customer' , 'mac_address'] ,
    $request->search  ,
    //back with all raws
    null,
    ['id'  , 'asc'] ,
    true ,
    30
);

$error = null;
if (is_string($terminals) {
    $error = json_decode($terminals);
    $terminals = null;
}

return view('terminal.search',compact('error', 'terminals'));
});
```

then on your view:

```
@if ($terminals)
    @foreach($terminals as $trm)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$trm->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$trm->customer}}</td>
            <th>{{$trm->mac_address}}</th>
            <th>{{$trm->modem_type}}</th>
            <th>{{$trm->satellite}}</th>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    There is an error: {{ $error['message'] }}
@endif
```

## My recommendation

Reading this package source code, it looks poor and amateur, full of bugs and bad designed.

There's a good package for full text search that I love and use it, it's the  [nicolaslopezj/searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable).

Another good package is the [jarektkaczyk/eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence).